# Firestore rules: fetch message thread by threadId in secure way

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

### Assumptions

I'm using Firestore and I can't set the correct rule for it.

Suppose there's a chat app.
And there are **threads** and **messages** collections.

**threads** attributes

> createdAt
>   userAId
>   userBId

**messages** attributes

> threadId
>   senderId
>   receiverId

I set the security rule as followed since I don't want my users to see messages of other users(omitted the irrelevant part):

```
match /messages/{messageId} {
  allow read: if isAuthenticated() && 
  (request.auth.uid == resource.data.senderId || request.auth.uid == resource.data.receiverId);
}
```

Suppose we have only one thread and only one message of that thread saved in firestore.

### Problem

When I execute the following query from my web app with authenticated user, it says insufficient permission of firestore even though the query is requesting the thread where the user is sender or receiver as required in rules.

```
const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .where('threadId', '==', someThreadId)
    .get()
```

However, when I execute the following query that fetchs the message by documentId, it returns the  message successfully.

```
const documentQuerySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(specificMessageId)
    .get()
```

### Workaround

I'm forced to write 2 queries and I don't want since it's not effective.

```
const qs1 = await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('messages')
  .where('senderId', '==', someUserId)
  .where('threadId', '==', someThreadId)
  .get()

const qs2 = await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('messages')
  .where('receiverId', '==', someUserId)
  .where('threadId', '==', someThreadId)
  .get()

messages = ${merge 2 messages list above}
```

### Quesetion

How can I fetch all messages of a thread by threadId while setting a correct security rules so that messages wouldn't be read by other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to realize is that Firebase's server-side security rules don't filter the data. They merely ensure that any operation your code tries to perform is authorizes. So to securely get filtered data, your code and security rules need to work together. For full details on this, see the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

Since your rules only allow reading messages that have the correct value for `senderId` or `receiverId`, your query needs to filter for one of those fields too. Just ensuring that the `threadId` belongs to an allowed user isn't enough. That would require that Firestore read all documents to ensure they meet your security rules, which it can never do at scale.

So your "workaround" is actually the correct solution for this. Alternatively, you might want to consider storing each thread in a separate collection, so that you can secure access on the collection level and bypass the conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My bad the answer was in the link.
I understood that even though filtering by threadId ensures either senderId or userId is equal to auth uid but technically it can be different. That's why insufficient permission error.
**Another question**
I didn't understand your alternative way very well.
That means storing messages as subcollection of threads?
Or storing threads under users collection?

Comment: If you store the conversation/messages for each thread in a separate collection, you won't need to use a query to access them as you can just load all documents in that collection. Typically you'd make that collection at a path like `/threads/$threadid/messages`, which is known as a subcollection in Firestore.